# Dolphin File Picker everywhere

Tags: filesystems, kde, qt, dolphin

I'm currently on KDE 5.51

Is it possible to use the dolphin file picker **everywhere**?

Some apps use the Qt file picker. This gets annoying as I prefer the single click in dolphin and don't want to duplicate my folder bookmarks.

**Beautiful** dolphin picker:

[image: Preferred dolphin picker]

*Disgusting* Qt File picker:

[image: Qt File picker]

Comment: This would be nice, but I wouldn't bet on it being possible. They probably have different APIs. A word of advice: It pays to be civil. Calling an interface "disgusting" is inflammatory and disrespects the many years of hard work that have gone into QT. This is especially true for something which is just your opinion. Linux folks disagree on just about everything, but the reason it works is that at least some of those folks manage to stay objective enough to have meaningful discussions about how to make things better.